# How to post a config in Angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, authentication

I have got an Angular2 Application with a config file lying on the server (/assets/data/config.json). This file contains urls to different services of the backend, e.g. Loggingservice, Appservice and Identityservice. Loading the file is not a problem, but if I want to update the file, the server responses with a 404...

Is it possible to put a new config onto the server without an additional service, just with the Node.js server? The authorization header of the request has to be validated serverside against a hardcoded hash

my update function looks like the following:

```
public setConfig(config: IAppConfig, authHash: string): void {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': authHash
    })
  };

  this.http.put<IAppConfig>(this.configPath, config, httpOptions)
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => {
      this.logger.log(this, 'configuration successfully updated!');
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.logger.error(this, 'configuration could not be updated!' + error.error);          
  });
}
```

Comment: Call api endpoint and do fs.write the data from request. Why not?

Comment: You need to create a route for update config in backend(server side), you have created for `GET` only not `PUT`